# How can I recursively update all records in a database based on whether they are linked to a single database change?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, prisma

I have a series of redirects that we are storing in a DB. The redirects all have a source and a destination. I want to be able to update redirects that link to one another so that they go straight to the final endpoint rather than having to redirect one by one through each path. i.e., something like this:

If there already exists a redirect from resource A → B, and a new redirect B → C is added, I want that to be resolved as:

A redirect from A → C;
A redirect from B → C.

If there already exists redirects A → B and C → D, and a new redirect B → C is added, I want that to be resolved as:

A redirect from A → D;
A redirect from B → D;
A redirect from C → D.

I can do it for the earliest point in the redirect chain (i.e. I can successfully update from A - D), but it doesn't seem to propagate through the rest of the previous endpoints.

I guess I'm asking more about methodology here. I cannot get my head around the logical steps that I would need to enact in order to make this change. I think it should probably include recursion, and that I should recursively look for the next endpoint int eh chain and then update accordingly, but that's about as far as I get when it comes to the logic of it.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, etc.? If it has recursive CTE, you should be able to use that in an `UPDATE` query. Otherwise you'll need to do the recursion in JavaScript.